# Trouble parsing JSON in ActionScript 3 -- "Unexpected c encountered"

Tags: json, actionscript-3

I am trying to parse a JSON file in [ActionScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActionScript) 3.

So far I imported this...

```
import com.adobe.serialization.json.JSON;
```

I have created the [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) class:

```
[Embed(source="myfile.json",mimeType="application/octet-stream")]
private var json_file:Class;
```

And then I try to parse the JSON

```
var jsonObj:Object = JSON.decode(json_file);
```

When I run the `JSON.decode` line, I get this error:

```
JSONParseError: Unexpected c encountered
```

I have tried to find out what I am doing wrong, but Google Search didn't seem to help. I have tried different and basic JSON files to ensure it isn't my file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I read the API wrong. The decode function needs a string, not a class. Here was my solution:

```
var bytes:ByteArray = new json_file();
var json:String = bytes.readUTFBytes(bytes.length);     
var jsonObj:Object = JSON.decode(json);
```

Answer (score 0):

`json_file` is a `Class`, rather than an instance. You should just need to pass a new instance of `json_file` to the decoder:

```
var jsonObj:Object = JSON.decode(new json_file());
```